# Confusing error when implementing an interface implemented by a class

Tags: typescript

I get the following error:

> Type '(ctx: any) => Promise<{ user: any; categories: any; }>' is not assignable to type '((ctx: NuxtContext) => Promise) | undefined'

When I defining the following class in Typescript:

```
export default class App extends Vue implements NUXT {
  async asyncData(ctx) {
    await ctx.store.dispatch('loadAllCategories');
    const user = ctx.store.state.user;
    const categories = ctx.store.state.categories;
    return { user, categories };
}
```

Where NUXT is an interface defined as:

```
export interface NUXT {
  fetch?: <T = any>(ctx: NuxtContext) => Promise<T>;
  asyncData?: <T = any>(ctx: NuxtContext) => Promise<T>;
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface NuxtContext {
  state: any;
  process: any;
}
```

This is befuddling to me as I'd expect the class which implements NUXT to implicitly know that the `asyncData` signature implicitly. Furthermore, the error makes no sense; does it? I mean the `Promise<{ user: any; categories: any; }>` returned would fit into the requirement for `Promise<all>`, right?

Comment: @rajash that shouldn't matter, _implicit_ typing is very powerful and that's what is being aimed for here.

Answer (score 0):

> This is befuddling to me as I'd expect the class which implements NUXT to implicitly know that the asyncData signature implicitly.

`implements` does not infer the types of implemented methods. It only *enforces* that the annotation are compatible. This is by design in TypeScript.

> I mean the Promise<{ user: any; categories: any; }> returned would fit into the requirement for Promise, right?

Yes. However typescript is not inferring the return type's generic. The following is a simplified version of the bug:

```
export interface NUXT {
    foo<T>(): Promise<T>
}

export default class App implements NUXT {
    foo(): Promise<null> { // null is not assignable to type T
        return Promise.resolve(null); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is by design that it doesn't use type information in an _implements_ clause?

Comment: Is there a way for me to "inject" typing into the properties in the Vue class (as I have no control over the class itself?